# Ошибка has no zero argument constructor Intent Service

Tags: java, android, android-service

Никак не могу понять в чем ошибка. Использую конструктор без аргумента,но при этом все равно ловлю этот эксепшен.

```
public class BackGroundService extends IntentService {


    public BackGroundService() {
        super("BackGroundService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        // Use reflection to trigger a method from 'StatusBarManager'

        @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") Object statusBarService = getSystemService("statusbar");
        Class<?> statusBarManager = null;

        try {
            statusBarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Method collapseStatusBar = null;

        try {

            // Prior to API 17, the method to call is 'collapse()'
            // API 17 onwards, the method to call is `collapsePanels()`

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 16) {
                collapseStatusBar = statusBarManager.getMethod("collapsePanels");
            } else {
                collapseStatusBar = statusBarManager.getMethod("collapse");
            }
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        collapseStatusBar.setAccessible(true);

        try {
            collapseStatusBar.invoke(statusBarService);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Вызов осуществляется от сюда

```
public void collapseNowFirst() {

     // Initialize 'intent service'
     if (intentService == null) {
        intentService = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BackGroundService.class);
     }

     // If window focus has been lost && activity is not in a paused state
     // Its a valid check because showing of notification panel
     // steals the focus from current activity's window, but does not
     // 'pause' the activity
     if (!currentFocus && !isPaused) {
        startService(intentService);
     } else 
        stopService(intentService);
}
```

Comment: Этот класс в отдельном файле? Clean project и удаление приложения с аппарата пробовали?

Comment: класс случайно не внутренний?

Answer (score 0):

Код выглядит правильным, очень похоже что по каким-то причинам компилятор "не видит" новой версии файла.

Ради эксперимента попробуйте создать новый класс `BackGroundService1`, скопировав туда весь код и использовать его вместо `BackGroundService`. Если дело именно в обновлении, то ошибка должна пропасть.

Comment: К чему эта магия? Автору надо учиться инструментами разработки правильно пользоваться а не копипастить.

Comment: Это не магия, это эксперимент, если покажет что в реальности класс закешировался - надо читать как правильно пользоваться инструментами разработки, если нет - то разбираться что не так.